Error while running Python code when trying to use the QAD plugin
After installing the QAD plugin, when I try to use it, an error related to Python appears on the screen.
How can I fix this problem and use the QAD plugin?

TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:   resize(self, a0: QSize): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'   resize(self, w: int, h: int): argument 2 has unexpected type 'float' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/Usuario/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qad\qad_textwindow.py", line 1166, in onTextChanged
    self.parentWidget().resizeEdits()
  File "C:\Users/Usuario/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qad\qad_textwindow.py", line 348, in resizeEdits
    self.chronologyEdit.resize(w, chronologyEditHeight)
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  resize(self, a0: QSize): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
  resize(self, w: int, h: int): argument 2 has unexpected type 'float'


Versión de Python: 3.12.3 (main, Apr 14 2024, 17:21:43) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)] 
Versión de QGIS: 3.34.6-Prizren Prizren, 623828f5 

Ruta de Python:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/Usuario/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/Usuario/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.6\apps\grass\grass83\etc\python
C:\Users\Usuario\Documents
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.34.6\bin\python312.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.6\apps\Python312\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.6\apps\Python312\Lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.34.6\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.6\apps\Python312
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.6\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.6\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.6\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.6\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/Usuario/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
D:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_6.2.0.201711281614\pysrc```

**The above message appears when installing the QAD plugin. If I try to use it I get
the following error message:**

```Bueno, esto es vergonzoso !
Inappropriate argument type.
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  move(self, a0: QPoint): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  move(self, ax: int, ay: int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  File "C:\Users/Usuario/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qad\qad_dynamicinput.py", line 2878, in moveCtrls
    self.edits[QadDynamicInputEditEnum.EDIT_DIST_PREV_PT].move(editPt.x(), editPt.y())
  File "C:\Users/Usuario/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qad\qad_dynamicinput.py", line 2775, in mouseMoveEvent
    self.moveCtrls(mousePos)
  File "C:\Users/Usuario/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qad\qad_dynamicinput.py", line 2535, in show
    self.mouseMoveEvent(mousePos)
  File "C:\Users/Usuario/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qad\qad_getpoint.py", line 677, in setStartPoint
    self.dynamicEditInput.show(True, self.canvas.mouseLastXY()) # visualizzo e resetto input dinamico
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users/Usuario/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qad\cmd\qad_circle_maptool.py", line 169, in setMode
    self.setStartPoint(self.centerPt)
  File "C:\Users/Usuario/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qad\cmd\qad_circle_cmd.py", line 182, in run
    self.getPointMapTool().setMode(Qad_circle_maptool_ModeEnum.CENTER_PT_KNOWN_ASK_FOR_RADIUS)
  File "C:\Users/Usuario/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qad\qad_commands.py", line 577, in run
    if self.command.run(msgMapTool, msg) == True:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users/Usuario/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qad\qad_commands.py", line 337, in continueCommandFromMapTool
    if self.actualCommand.run(True) == True: # comando terminato
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^```


You need to report the issue to the QAD plugin repository at https://github.com/gam17/QAD
